# Explicit analytical solution of set of ODEs or Numerical solution without Boundary conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am trying to model prestall dynamics in a centrifugal compressor. For this task, I assume a known steady mean flow and small perturbations of flow quantities whose dynamics grow in time, leading up to stall. The idea is to couple analytical solutions for each subdomain to that of the next subdomain, using transmission matrices, written in terms of the explicit solutions and arbitrary constants.

[Compression system model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpbvl.jpg)

For the blade free regions shown in Fig 1, (inlet and exit axial ducts and vaneless diffuser), I am solving the 2D linearized compressible Euler equations for the perturbed quantities only and for the bladed region (impeller), I assume a semi-actuator disk and just write matching conditions for the perturbed quantities across the actuator disk, so I can couple the upstream axial duct solution to the downstream radial space solution. For the axial ducts, I am solving in $x-\theta$ and for the radial space, I am solving in $r-\theta$.

The aim is to get a system matrix of the form $\mathbb X_{sys} = \mathbb T_{ax,n}(x_{3-4},s)^{-1}*\mathbb T_{rad,n}(r_{2-3},s)*\mathbb B^{1-2}_{imp,n}(s)*\mathbb T_{ax,n}(x_{0-1},s)$
that represents the dynamics of the whole system in terms of the Laplace variable $s$ and then using known boundary conditions at station $0$ and at station $4$, solve the dispersion equation that arises to get the system eigenvalues and thus, stability information.

**The equations in $x-\theta$ are:**

$ \frac {∂δρ}{∂t} + \bar V_x \frac {∂δρ}{∂x} +ρ ̅  \frac {∂δV_x}{∂x} + \frac {1}{r}(\bar V_\theta \frac {\partial δρ}{∂θ} + ρ ̅ \frac {\partial δV_θ}{∂θ})= 0 $...................................mass

$ \frac{∂δV_x}{∂t} + \bar V_x \frac{\partial\delta V_x}{\partial x} + \frac{\bar V_\theta}{r} \frac{\partial\delta V_x}{\partial \theta} = - \frac{1}{\bar\rho} \frac{\partial P}{\partial x}$
   ...................................................x - momentum

$ \frac{∂δV_\theta}{∂t} + \bar V_x \frac{\partial\delta V_\theta}{\partial x} + \frac{\bar V_\theta}{r} \frac{\partial\delta V_\theta}{\partial \theta} = - \frac{1}{\bar\rho}* \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial P}{\partial \theta}$
   ............................................$\theta$ - momentum

$ \frac{∂δP}{∂t} + \bar V_x \frac{\partial\delta P}{\partial x} + \frac{\bar V_\theta}{r} \frac{\partial\delta P}{\partial \theta} = a^2 (\frac{∂δ\rho}{∂t} + \bar V_x \frac{\partial\delta \rho}{\partial x} + \frac{\bar V_\theta}{r} \frac{\partial\delta \rho}{\partial \theta})$
   ....................energy

For $r-\theta$, the mean flow is non uniform and approximates a logarithmic spiral. This led to the assumption of a free vortex background flow, replacing the known mean flow radial velocity and circumferential velocity with flow rate (Q) and circulation ($\Gamma$) constants respectively.
The set of ODEs are shown below.

**For $r-\theta$**,

$ \frac {∂δρ}{∂t} + \frac{\bar Q}{r} \frac {∂δρ}{∂r} +ρ ̅  \frac {∂δV_r}{∂r} + \frac {1}{r}(\frac{\bar \Gamma}{r} \frac {\partial δρ}{∂θ} + ρ ̅ \frac {\partial δV_θ}{∂θ})= 0 $...................................mass

$ \frac{∂δV_r}{∂t} + \frac{\bar Q}{r}\frac{\partial\delta V_r}{\partial r} + \frac{\bar \Gamma}{r^2} \frac{\partial\delta V_x}{\partial \theta} = - \frac{1}{\bar\rho} \frac{\partial P}{\partial r}$
   ...................................................r - momentum

$ \frac{∂δV_\theta}{∂t} + \frac{\bar Q}{r} \frac{\partial\delta V_\theta}{\partial r} + \frac{\bar \Gamma}{r^2} \frac{\partial\delta V_\theta}{\partial \theta} = - \frac{1}{\bar\rho}* \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial P}{\partial \theta}$
   ............................................$\theta$ - momentum

$ \frac{∂δP}{∂t} + \frac{\bar Q}{r} \frac{\partial\delta P}{\partial r} + \frac{\bar \Gamma}{r^2} \frac{\partial\delta P}{\partial \theta} = a^2 (\frac{∂δ\rho}{∂t} + \frac{\bar Q}{r} \frac{\partial\delta \rho}{\partial r} + \frac{\bar \Gamma}{r^2} \frac{\partial\delta \rho}{\partial \theta})$
   .....................energy

Performing some simplifications, and assuming a periodic solution in time and a sum of n spatial harmonic solutions in $\theta$, taking a Laplace transform in time and a Fourier transform in $\theta$ reduces the sets of PDEs to linear implicit ODEs for each perturbed quantity in the $x-\theta$ domain, which is readily solved to give solutions of the form, for the nth harmonic perturbation solution.

$$ \delta P = \sum_{n=0}^n {\left(A_n(s)e^{\alpha x} + B_n(s)e^{\beta x}\right)e^{jn\theta}} $$

$$ \delta V_x = \sum_{n=0}^n {\left(A_n(s)e^{\alpha x} + B_n(s)e^{\beta x} +C_n(s)e^{\gamma x}\right)e^{jn\theta}} $$

$$ \delta V_\theta = \sum_{n=0}^n {\left(\frac{jn}{r\bar V_x}A_n(s)e^{\alpha x} + \frac{jn}{r\bar V_x}B_n(s)e^{\beta x} +C_n(s)e^{\gamma x}\right)e^{jn\theta}} $$

$$ \delta \rho = \sum_{n=0}^n {\left(A_n(s)e^{\alpha x} + B_n(s)e^{\beta x} + D_n(s)e^{\gamma x}\right)e^{jn\theta}} $$

Where the Fourier coefficients $ A_n(s)$ and $B_n(s)$ correspond to potential growth and decay modes, $C_n(s)$ corresponds to a vortical mode and $D_n(s)$ corresponds to an entropy mode.

And so, I can represent the axial duct solutions in terms of a transmission matrix shown below, that I can couple to the impeller transmission matrix and transmission matrices for other sub components to get the full system dynamics

$$ \left[ \begin{matrix}\delta V_x\\
\delta V_\theta\\
\delta P\\
\delta \rho \end{matrix} \right ] = \mathbb T_{ax,n} \left[ \begin{matrix} A_n(s)\\
B_n(s)\\
C_n(s)\\
D_n(s) \end{matrix} \right ] $$

**For $r-\theta$**, because, I could not find any way to simplify the PDE set, I first reduced the set of PDEs to ODEs using the Laplace and Fourier transforms as shown below and attempt a solution for the set of ODEs

$s\tilde\rho_n +  \frac{\bar Q}{r} \frac {d\tilde\rho_n}{dr} +\bar\rho \frac {d\tilde V_r,_n}{dr} + \frac {jn}{r}(\frac{\bar \Gamma}{r} \tilde \rho_n + ρ ̅ \tilde V_\theta,_n) = 0 $...................................mass

$ s\tilde V_r,_n +  \frac{\bar Q}{r} \frac {d\tilde V_r,_n}{dr} + \frac{jn\bar \Gamma}{r^2} \tilde V_r,_n = - \frac{1}{\bar\rho} \frac{d \tilde P_n}{d r}$
   ...................................................r - momentum

$ s\tilde V_\theta,_n +  \frac{\bar Q}{r} \frac {d\tilde V_\theta,_n}{dr} + \frac{jn\bar \Gamma}{r^2} \tilde V_\theta,_n = - \frac{1}{\bar\rho}* \frac{1}{r} * jn \tilde P_n$
   .......................................$\theta$ - momentum

$ s\tilde P_n +  \frac{\bar Q}{r} \frac {d\tilde P_n}{dr} + \frac{jn\bar \Gamma}{r^2} \tilde P_n = a^2 (s\tilde \rho_n +  \frac{\bar Q}{r} \frac {d\tilde \rho_n}{dr} + \frac{jn\bar \Gamma}{r^2} \tilde \rho_n)$
   ..........................energy

For the set of linear ODEs describing the radial space dynamics, I am unable to find explicit solutions (I have tried hand calc, MATLAB and Maple) and so, I cannot build $\mathbb T_{rad,n}$. Is there anyway I can find explicit solutions for these in terms of the known quantities only? In the event that I cannot, is it possible to find a numerical solution by discretizing r, but without giving boundary conditions, since I do not know the boundary conditions between $2$ and $3$, but overall system boundary conditions.

Given that I do not intend to solve the set of equations, but to cast the system matrix as a dispersion problem for which I get the system eigenvalues $s = \sigma + j\omega$ that inform the system stability based on the sign of $\sigma$, how do I handle the added complexity that comes from not having an explicit solution set to the ODEs in the radial subdomain?